# How to speed up window onload function in custom js?

Tags: javascript

I am confused in JS window onload. I need a JS script that helps to load all images, js, ads after complete page load. 
I want to speed up.

Currently, I am using the onload script.

```
jQuery(window).load(function() { // makes sure the whole site is loaded
    $('#preloader').delay(0).fadeOut(); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.
    $('body').delay(0).css({
        'overflow': 'visible'
    });
```

Please help me to overcome this problem and load content after the page has loaded.

Comment: You’re looking for ‘lazy loading’. Google that

Comment: What about lazy loading? It will help to load content, images, ads after the page have loaded, How to apply it with the better resource.